# How to create a stack based icon using Affinity Designer?

Tags: vector, logo, affinity-designer, isometric

I am new to logo design and I was wondering how I could create a stack based logo like Apple does for their frameworks.

The logos look like this:

[image: ShazamKit Icon]

Is this even possible using Affinity Designer or is this some kind of 3D render?

Comment: It's merely isometric squares, rounded and stacked on top of one another. I don't know Affinity Designer at all, but I'd be exceptionally shocked if such [rudimentary shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj1um.gif) like this were not possible in that app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

3D rendering would be a handy shortcut, but it's not needed in cases this simple. 2D crafting works as well although the right projection and shading gradients doesn't come automatically, one must draw them. Fortunately the projection is the simplest possible 3D looking one (=isometric) and the apparent light also is simple.

The next example is done in Inkscape as pure 2D job. It has nothing that isn't available in Affinity D.

[image]

In the left there's a rounded square, a circle and a white random scribble. The rounded square is rotated 45 degrees. It's not white to make it well visible. The rounding is not an effect, it's converted to curves (=to path in Inkscape). The scribble also is a white filled area with no stroke to make it easily scalable.

The black lines are used only as markers to be able  to insert a node to the exact midpoints of the corner curves of the square. The nodes are shown in the right. Actually the vertical line is not needed in this case, new nodes are later used only in 9 and 3 o'clock corners

The process continues by selecting all and scaling vertically to 71% for isometric projection. It's done in the left in the next image:

[image]

In the middle a copy of the square is made, sent to back and colored differently to make it well visible.

In the right a rectangle is drawn between the inserted mid arc nodes. It fills the gap. In the left in the next image the bottom square and the rectangle are combined as Boolean union and sent to back:

[image]

a red and a green copy of the dark grey shape are made and sent to back. They snap well if one has snap to nodes ON.

The shading is inserted. I jumped over where the fence was lowest i.e. made an union of the duplicates of the red, green and the dark grey shapes. After making the Boolean union a gradient fill was inserted, the shape got blending mode Multiply and it was placed just below the light grey square in the layering order. A copy of the gradient shape is inserted to far right only to show it.

As you can see, your example contains subtle gradient fills also on the grey and blue top shapes. With them one can make the button look like the top surface was slightly curved, no matter the edges look straight. I skip them.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. Result looks very nice.